# How to use or create a Rich Text Editor in REACT-NATIVE?

Tags: javascript, react-native

im new in react-native and im making a notebloc, so after a loooong time searching how to do this:

[image]

the conclusion is that I need a Rich Text Editor or create one by myself, but like i said, im new, very very very new in this programming world, so I really dont know where to start or do, apreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check following npm which may help to complete your requirement.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cn-richtext-editor

https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor

[image]